# Shiny example files don't show the proper interface

Tags: r, shiny

I installed the `shiny` package, but after running the example file: `runExample("01_hello")`, the pop up does not show the expected interface (for example, there's no sliding bar, and nothing happens after entering manually a number of bins). I see the same effect if I view it in an external browser as well. See the below picture for better understanding. I tried similar cases and it is always the same...

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

The app that opens looks like this:

[image]

But should look like this:

[image]

I just installed the latest version of R and RStudio for Windows10 (64bit) but still have the issue... Also tried to update the graphic drivers in case the problem was with them, but no solution so far. Any hints?

Here the session info.

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 R6_2.4.0        
 [5] magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.3.1     rlang_0.3.4      rstudioapi_0.10 
 [9] tools_3.5.3      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.2      xfun_0.6        
[13] compiler_3.5.3   pkgconfig_2.0.2  knitr_1.22       tidyselect_0.2.5
[17] tibble_2.1.1
```

Comment: Hi divibisan, it happens also when I open the results in a browser...

Comment: I assume you've reinstalled `shiny` and R and tried in a fresh R session?

Comment: Yes, just did that and I get the same; also opened it with IE, Chrome and Mozilla without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I got an answer. My R library was saved under a path that was not compatible with shiny (meaning that the path had special signs like à). I solved the problem deleting the libraries and reinstalling them in a new path C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library. For that may be needed to run R-Studio as admin.

Thanks for the help, was much appreciated :)